# In Spring Boot, How to assign the exact same random port to another property in configure

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am running spring boot with grpc-spring-boot-starter as a grpc-server and also configured as an eureka client.

Since I'm trying to launch more instances later, i want to assign a random port for my grpc service so I made `grpc.port=0`

The problem is, I also want `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort` to be the exact same port as `grpc.port`.Here is my configure.

```
grpc:
  port: 0

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  application:
    name: grpc-service
  instance:
    securePortEnabled: false
    nonSecurePort: ${grpc.port}
    instance_id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

The problem is, I always get `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort` to be 0 which is not what I want. I know the random port is assigned during runtime. However are there anyway to make the `grpc.port` and `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort` always the same after spring boot assigned the random port?

Answer (score 4):

You can put random port following an interval by following way:

```
grpc:
  port: ${random.int[9000,9900]}

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  application:
    name: grpc-service
  instance:
    securePortEnabled: false
    nonSecurePort: ${grpc.port}
```

Comment: Thank you for you kind answer. I think it's enough for local development.

Comment: It's OK @gyorou if this answer helped you, please mark it as answer and vote it. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, actually after I tried this configure, I found nonSecurePort is not the same as grpc.port, it also got a random number from 9000 to 9900.